# Tracking Traffic With Same Domain but Different URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

My domain: hospital.org/app

2 Type of user:
 **- Patient
 - Admin**

Example URL for **Patient**: hospital.org/app/fp/main/PA_MedicationsProgress.php

Example URL for **Admin**: hospital.org/app/fa/main/Admin_Dashboard.php

Currently, I am tracking data for both Patient & Admin but I need to separate the data for 2 types of users here. The URL for the patient will contain "PA" and the URL for the admin will contain "Admin".

**My current solution:**

Example URL for **Patient**: hospital.org/app/fp/main/PA/MedicationsProgress.php

Example URL for **Admin**: hospital.org/app/fa/main/Admin/Dashboard.php

But this will require me to change the URL and set up different properties which are not integrated into 1 report. Is there any way for me to show the data differently for these two users without changes these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter or use a segment in the same Property based the currently URL: `/fp/` or `/fa/` without modify the page name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is it the "+ Add Segment" on top of the page? As for this, I can't find any URL filter in the search when I type URL.

Comment: Share your segment configuration and an example of page report.